# assign min-width

Tags: css

I've my HTML code as below

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="wrapHeader">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="toolbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS as

```
#header{
    height: 55px;
}

#wrapHeader{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo{
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    height: 50px;
}

#toolbar{
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

Here, logo width = 125px & #toolbar width = 800px;

What I want is, when the browser is resized, I want to stop the fluid structure at 960px (which I tried by declaring min-width = 960px at #wrapHeader although I'm not sure if it's the right way to do).
Right away, I don't want to give the #wrapHeader width as 960px as it won't expand the #logo and #toolbar as the screen expands.

Kindly help.

Comment: What browser are you using? The min-width property is not supported in every browser unfortunately. More info on W3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add the mind-width to a html definition.

```
html {
min-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: You can also expand the logo and toolbar when you expand the wrapper.